# Dynamically monitoring java object field and method return values

Tags: java, reflection, monitoring

I m trying to develop a simulation application. I need to monitor all java objects in simulation environment. During the execution of a simulation, user defined objects methods are called periodically in each tick. I want to trace all field values and method return values of all objects. For example,

```
public class Person{
int energy,x,y;
public Person(){
   this.energy = new Random().nextInt(0,10); 
}

@ScheduledMethod(start=1, interval=1)
void step(){
   energy--;
   // move random x,y
   move();
}

void move(){
   this.x= new Random().nextInt(1,50);
   this.y = new Random().nexInt(1,50);
} }
```

In my simulator each person instance energy value in each tick until person is dead is traced and saved. Simulation developers generally uses randomized functions so calling a method twice may not be return the same value like x,y value of the Person.

By using reflection API i can access field values dynamically (energy value of the person can be accessed.) but i need to access method return values (x,y value of the person is changed in each call of the move). When i call method using reflection execution of the method is twiced. So, i need to handle method calling differently.

I mention that i need a monitoring mechanism like JAVA Debugging API. How i can do that during the execution of simulation.I need to watch all fields and method return values like debugging code in execution.

Any idea.

Thanks for ideas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand what you're asking correctly, you want to capture changes in values of raw fields after a call to a method with your annotation.

There are a lot of possible solutions to this, depending on how simple the client code needs to be, and how complicated a framework you want to write, and what you actually need it to do.  Here are some ideas:

- Have a common base class for simulation objects, and give subclasses a way to store values in a `Map<String,Object>` you give them, instead of in a raw field;  they you supply a subclass of `Map` which records changes, and your code can simply ask the object what has changed since the last time it was called
- Instrument the bytecode on the fly when you load it, using something like [BCEL](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-bcel/), and replace local field accesses with calls to dynamically generated getters and setters, and do the above bookkeeping there
- Do the above, but at compile time by dynamically generating subclasses which contain the bookkeeping code

The last two options are non-trivial to implement, so I'd strongly suggest considering the first option first.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Tim. First option is my solution also. But i want change to the developers watching all expressions like Java debugger. İ want to observe the watch expressions during the execution like result of a method call without effecting the execution behavior of the code. Is a debugger instrument the byte code at run time?

Comment: Add some kind of listener support to your Map - override ``put()`` to notify listeners of what changed.  Then stick whatever kind of UI you want to on top of that.